# How to Change drop down arrow Arrow for Spinner Control in Android?

Tags: android

I am writing an Android App in which I am using Spinner Control. I customized my spinner control by creating my own list. I want to change the drop down arrow present beside the spinner control . Can anyone help me how to change the drop down arrow of spinner control . I want to replace that arrow by own arrow Image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to make a style and then set that style of your spinner. The spinner's background with the arrow work as a button. So, if you make a style for a button with the various states button pressed, button selected then it will work for you. You can't change the arrow only, you have to change the full background. hope you have understand what I meant...

Comment: The default framework style for Spinners: http://goo.gl/sqo4C and the state list definition for pressed, disabled, etc. states: http://goo.gl/fzqhH Set android:background on the Spinner element in your layout to a custom state list for your app for a one-off change, or define your own style or theme as shown here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html